# Good resource for learning civicrm and drupal

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

I want to learn civiCRM and drupal.
Please tell me some good resources and tutorial with example.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are lots of tutorials available for CiviCRM. Here are some of the links that were useful for me while i was training someone 2-4 years ago.

- https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=38994278
- https://docs.civicrm.org/
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxexhDSzSME
- https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbmFxo3HyO9gaNG40byQjiQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5bjr0s02NQ -- CiviCRM 101 Webinar
  Series for Newbies
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ERGOSCIny0c -- CiviCRM 101 Webinar
- https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjSU7YfE0E01HW7JPVAI80XDI0sgOSPDs

You can also look to past CiviCRM conferences. A lot of presenters upload their notes to the session pages or visiting [local events](https://civicrm.org/local-events) if they are held nearby your places.

Similarly you can find lots of [videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=drupal%207%20training) and documentation on drupal.

If you have good knowledge of PHP, MYSQL, Javascript then try to submit a patch for [open issues](https://lab.civicrm.org/explore/groups) or [feature request](https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/feature-requests/-/issues).

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend http://codekarate.com for Drupal.

For CiviCRM the online documentation is excellent.

https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/