# Time estimate for setting up CiviCRM?

Tags: installation

I volunteer with a small non-profit and we recently decided to create a new CRM using CiviCRM. I am a complete novice with this and am learning it all from scratch - really appreciating the community and all the help on offer.

As we are planning out the work I am struggling to come up with a rough estimate for how long it will take and was hoping someone could advise. I realise this is a bit 'how long is a piece of string' but it would be good to hear from peoples' experiences how long similar-ish projects can take, either in hours or days for different stages.

We currently have around 300 members and we are planning to start off with a fairly simple CRM focussing on membership management. The key features/aims are:

- Integrated with our Wordpress website (currently using shared hosting but may move to cloud).
- Securely hold very basic member data; provisionally names, email, region, membership subscription amount, and have some basic tags.
- Contact groups, with some groups having access to specific pages on our website (e.g. 'members' have more access than 'supporters').
- Automated updating of the database when members join, leave etc.
- Connected with a payment processor.
- Automated emails following certain triggers e.g. lapsed payments.
- Ability to set up events, invite different contact groups, and record attendees.
- Email and event templates.

If I have said anything that doesn't make sense please let me know! Here to learn.

Many thanks,
Nick Sharma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nicky welcome to CiviCRM SE. Your requirement seems to be very simple and straight forward and can achieved using CiviCRM without any writing any custom code(Can say less than a day for someone who is well versed with CiviCRM or a week or more for a newbie).

You can contact [experts](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) based on your country you living or the organization is setup for cost. Or if you want to do it by your self there are ample of tutorials available online which I believe is sufficient for your requirement.

https://docs.civicrm.org/

https://civicrm.org/videos

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxexhDSzSME

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d40gJqV7qp0

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rEtclUjxBwA

[Good resource for learning civicrm and drupal](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26585/good-resource-for-learning-civicrm-and-drupal)

[CiviCRM training courses for beginners](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/civicrm-training-courses-for-beginners)

Comment: Some of the OP's requirements seem like they could be more or less complicated, depending on the details. Just working out how to map these requirements onto Civi's features could easily take more than a day for an expert in consultation with the client, depending on the details. I'd say a week for a newbie to do the whole thing is pretty optimistic. But Civi is a great fit for these needs!